# ng-checked not recognizing true/false when taken from localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code snippet below inside of my controller.  In my HTML, I have a checkbox with `ng-checked="enterToSend"` attached to it.  As well as an `ng-click="enterToSendCheck()"`

```
$scope.enterToSend = localStorage.getItem('enterToSend');

$scope.enterToSendCheck = function() {
    $scope.enterToSend = ($scope.enterToSend == false) ? true : false;

    localStorage.setItem('enterToSend', $scope.enterToSend);
}
```

It's updating properly in localstorage.  I open up localstorage, check it on/off and it updates to true/false in my browser.

However, when loading the page, using ng-checked or the regular checked attribute, it's checked (whether true or false).  Why is this?

Comment: may be 1 and 0 should be a better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` stores string representations only and `"true"` or `"false"` is not the same as `true` or `false`.

```
$scope.enterToSend = booleanFromString(localStorage.getItem('enterToSend'));


function booleanFromString(s) {
    if (s == 'true') return true;
    if (s == 'false') return false;

    throw new Error("Unable to convert '" + s + "' to a boolean, valid arguments are 'true' or 'false'");
}
```